# std::find fails on a std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T>> with a "no match for ‘operator==’" error when T is in a namespace

Tags: c++, vector, namespaces, reference-wrapper

I'm currently work on a large code project and wanted to take the opportunity to learn about and use namespaces. All of the classes I've defined reside within a single namespace, Test.

One of my classes, referred to here as Thing, has a unique ID. I need to be able to hold an std::vector of references to some Things, and so I'm using std::reference_wrappers. At points in the program, I need to remove certain std::reference_wrappers from the vector, so I use std::find:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

namespace Test {

class Thing {
private:
    const int id;

public:
    Thing(int id);
    const int ID() const;
};

}

Test::Thing::Thing(int id) : id(id) { }

const int Test::Thing::ID() const {
    return id;
}

inline bool operator==(const Test::Thing& lhs, const Test::Thing& rhs) {
    return lhs.ID() == rhs.ID();
}
inline bool operator!=(const Test::Thing& lhs, const Test::Thing& rhs) {
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}

int main() {
    Test::Thing t1(5);
    Test::Thing t2(7);

    auto ref1 = std::ref(t1);
    auto ref2 = std::ref(t2);

    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Test::Thing>> v;
    v.push_back(ref1);
    v.push_back(ref2);

    auto pos = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), ref2);
}
```

When I attempt to compile this, I get an error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘std::reference_wrapper<Test::Thing>’ and ‘const std::reference_wrapper<Test::Thing>’)
```

However, if I remove the namespace, the code compiles correctly:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Thing {
private:
    const int id;

public:
    Thing(int id);
    const int ID() const;
};

Thing::Thing(int id) : id(id) { }

const int Thing::ID() const {
    return id;
}

inline bool operator==(const Thing& lhs, const Thing& rhs) {
    return lhs.ID() == rhs.ID();
}
inline bool operator!=(const Thing& lhs, const Thing& rhs) {
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}

int main() {
    Thing t1(5);
    Thing t2(7);

    auto ref1 = std::ref(t1);
    auto ref2 = std::ref(t2);

    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Thing>> v;
    v.push_back(ref1);
    v.push_back(ref2);

    auto pos = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), ref2);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct solution is to move the operators into the namespace where [Argument-dependent lookup (ADL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) can find them:

```
namespace Test {

class Thing {
private:
    const int id;

public:
    Thing(int id);
    const int ID() const;
};


inline bool operator==(const Thing& lhs, const Thing& rhs) {
    return lhs.ID() == rhs.ID();
}
inline bool operator!=(const Thing& lhs, const Thing& rhs) {
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}

}

Test::Thing::Thing(int id) : id(id) { }

const int Test::Thing::ID() const {
    return id;
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c5ca9342bb9b6c0)

The same is already done by the standard library with operators such as `<<` for stream insertion.

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly that in order to use the classes built in `operator==` the `std::reference_wrapper` would need to be extended with it?